# Why showing path instead of icon in table cell

Tags: java, swing, icons, tablecell

I am newbie on java-swing. I am trying to add icon in table cell. but when i add ImageIcon in cell then it's showing only path instead of icon.

Here is my code.

```
 public void createGUI(ArrayList<String> params, String type) {

    try {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        model.addColumn("ParameterName");
        model.addColumn("ParameterType");
        model.addColumn("Operation");
        for (int i = 0; i < params.size() - 4; i++) {
            String param_name = params.get(i).toString().substring(0, params.get(i).toString().indexOf("["));
            String param_type = params.get(i).toString().substring(params.get(i).toString().indexOf("[") + 1, params.get(i).toString().indexOf("]"));
            //URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("");
            ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("/com/soastreamer/resources/delete_idle.png");
          //  JLabel label = new JLabel(image);
            model.addRow(new Object[]{param_name, param_type.toUpperCase(),image});

        }


        Action delete = new AbstractAction() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JTable table = (JTable) e.getSource();
                int modelRow = Integer.valueOf(e.getActionCommand());
                ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).removeRow(modelRow);
            }
        };
```

Here is image for clear understanding.

[image]

Please give me hint or any reference. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lies with your TableModel, you have to tell the table that it has to render an image in that column overriding the  `getColumnClass(int column)` method of the model.

Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4947154/2588463) by camickr.

**UPDATE**

Minimal example of a JTable with an ImageIcon using DefaultTableModel's renderer to paint it. I borrowed the `updateRowHeights()` code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1784601/2588463) again by camickr, without it the icon was bigger than the row and wasn't fully displayed.

The important thing here is that now when the renderer calls `getColumnClass(1)`, it gets `ImageIcon.class` so the code to render icons will be executed. By default this method would return `Object.class` and the renderer would ignore the fact that it's an icon.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class ImageIconTable
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ImageIconTable().initGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public void initGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();        
        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel()
        {
            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column)
            {
                if (column == 1) return ImageIcon.class; 
                return Object.class;
            }
        };
        tableModel.addColumn("Row 1");
        tableModel.addColumn("Icons Row");
        tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{"This cell is an Object", new ImageIcon("icon.jpg")});
        _table = new JTable(tableModel);

        updateRowHeights();

        frame.add(new JScrollPane(_table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void updateRowHeights()
    {
        try
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < _table.getRowCount(); row++)
            {
                int rowHeight = _table.getRowHeight();

                for (int column = 0; column < _table.getColumnCount(); column++)
                {
                    Component comp = _table.prepareRenderer(_table.getCellRenderer(row, column), row, column);
                    rowHeight = Math.max(rowHeight, comp.getPreferredSize().height);
                }
                _table.setRowHeight(row, rowHeight);
            }
        }
        catch(ClassCastException e) {}
    }

    private JTable _table;
}
```

It looks like this:

[image: Table displaying an icon]

Comment: can you update my code.. i am newbie on java swing so i don't understand how to do this?

Comment: @SandipArmalPatil No, I can't update your code but see my update with an example above. You have to integrate that in your code.

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you to use [ImageIo.read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.net.URL%29) and use the BufferedImage returned as argument for your `ImageIcon` object.
Second, use the [Class.getResource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) facility

```
YourClass.class.getResource("/com/soastreamer/resources/delete_idle.png");
```

Then, everything should work.

Comment: No, his ImageIcon code is fine, the problem is that he's rendering the ImageIcon as an Object.