# How to set space between cells so that cell's content is not erased

Tags: java, swing, jtable

My next annoying problem is to set Space between cells so that content of cells doesn't get erased.
I tried already all Internet solutions but they don't help because as I encrease border then content of cell is erased.
Here is what I tried:

```
public class DateFormatDemo extends JFrame
{
    private Border emptyBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5);
    private JTable dataSearchResultTable;

    public DateFormatDemo()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 5, 10));
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(initDataSearchResultTable()));
        super.getContentPane().add(panel);
        super.pack();
        super.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        super.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JTable initDataSearchResultTable()
    {
        dataSearchResultTable = new JTable(new MyTableModel()) {

            @Override
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)
            {
                JComponent component = (JComponent) super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
//              component.setBorder(emptyBorder);
                return component;
            }
        };
        dataSearchResultTable.setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension(5, 10));
        dataSearchResultTable.setSelectionBackground(new Color(0xaaaaff));
        dataSearchResultTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        dataSearchResultTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
        dataSearchResultTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        dataSearchResultTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        dataSearchResultTable.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
                    boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
            {
                JComponent component = (JComponent) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
                component.setBorder(emptyBorder);
                return component;
            }
        });
        return dataSearchResultTable;
    }

    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel
    {
        private String[] columnNames = { "First Name", "Last Name", "Timestamp", "Number", "Vegetarian" };
        private Object[][] data ;

        MyTableModel()
        {
            data = new Object[][] {
                    { "Vova", "KipokKipokKipokKipok", Timestamp.valueOf("2013-04-12 11:20:41"), new Integer(5),
                            new Boolean(true) },
                    { "Olia", "Duo", Timestamp.valueOf("2010-01-11 11:11:41"), new Integer(3), new Boolean(false) },
                    { "Oksana", "Stack", Timestamp.valueOf("2012-04-12 11:20:41"), new Integer(2), new Boolean(false) },
                    { "Petro", "White", Timestamp.valueOf("2010-04-12 11:20:21"), new Integer(20), new Boolean(true) },
                    { "Ivan", "Brown", Timestamp.valueOf("2011-04-11 11:20:41"), new Integer(10), new Boolean(true) } };
            fireTableDataChanged();
        }

        public int getColumnCount()
        {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        public int getRowCount()
        {
            return data.length;
        }

        public String getColumnName(int col)
        {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col)
        {
            if (data.length > 0 && data[0] != null) {
                return data[row][col];
            }
            return null;
        }

        /*
         * JTable uses this method to determine the default renderer/ editor for
         * each cell. If we didn't implement this method, then the last column
         * would contain text ("true"/"false"), rather than a check box.
         */
        public Class getColumnClass(int c)
        {
            Object valueAt = getValueAt(0, c);
            return valueAt == null ? Object.class : valueAt.getClass();
        }

        /*
         * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's editable.
         */
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col)
        {
                return true;
        }

        /*
         * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's data can
         * change.
         */
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col)
        {
            if (data.length > 0 && data[0] != null) {
                data[row][col] = value;
                fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException
    {
        new DateFormatDemo();
    }
}
```

Does anybody know how to set space between cells so that cell's content is not erased?

**SOLVED:**

```
dataSearchResultTable.setRowHeight(25);
        dataSearchResultTable.setRowMargin(5);
        dataSearchResultTable.getColumnModel().setColumnMargin(20);
```

But `rowMargin` causes selected row to be narrower than row borders. The solution is to set `rowHeight` only without `rowMargin`. This ensures that selection is not narrower than row itself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `setRowHeight()` method as you mentioned, I recommend you to use next method for your table([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783607/auto-adjust-the-height-of-rows-in-a-jtable/1784601#1784601)):

```
private void updateRowHeights(JTable table ) {
    for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
        int rowHeight = table.getRowHeight();
        for (int column = 0; column < table.getColumnCount(); column++) {
            Component comp = table.prepareRenderer(table.getCellRenderer(row, column), row, column);
            rowHeight = Math.max(rowHeight,comp.getPreferredSize().height);
        }
        table.setRowHeight(row, rowHeight);
    }
}
```

Because it calculates height for each row. In this case all your rows will be look fine.

When you use `setRowHeight()` isn't always solve problems of system default properties, try to add that line to your code for example and you will see what I mean `dataSearchResultTable.setFont(new Font("Arial", 1, 25));`

Comment: This method is good when cell-component is bigger than rowHeight but it is not my case

Comment: Java tutorial gives similar solution but for setting widths [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableRenderDemoProject/src/components/TableRenderDemo.java)