# display resultset in jtable cell with multiline

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, row-height

I am pulling database records from `MySql`, I am able to do this using the method below

```
private void txt_clientNameKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                           

    String sql = "Select client_id as 'Client ID', name_lastName as 'Full Name', case_number as 'Case #', hearing_date as 'Hearing Date', rtc_mtc as 'RTC/MTC', place as 'Place', status as 'Status', note as 'Notes', billing as 'Billed' from hearing_history where name_lastName like '%"+ txt_clientName.getText() +"%' ";

    try{
        if(conn==null){

            conn = ConnectDB.ConDB();
        }else{
            conn = ConnectDB.ConDB();
        }

        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));            

    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }finally {
        close();

    }
}
```

it is working fine but I have a column that should have a multiple line or to wrap the words to increase the height of the cell.

I am using java swing for 4 months now and I haven't seen/encountered advanced tricks to manipulate `jtable` as I wanted it to perform.

I searched this site and found shortest way to do it from this link

[Auto adjust the height of rows in a JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783607/auto-adjust-the-height-of-rows-in-a-jtable)

from camickr

```
private void updateRowHeights()
{
try 
{
    for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++)
    {
        int rowHeight = table.getRowHeight();

        for (int column = 0; column < table.getColumnCount(); column++)
        {
            Component comp = table.prepareRenderer(table.getCellRenderer(row, column), row, column);
            rowHeight = Math.max(rowHeight, comp.getPreferredSize().height);
        }

        table.setRowHeight(row, rowHeight);
    }
}
catch(ClassCastException e) {}
```

}

It is really a nice code I think but I tried it and I noticed that the height increase from `16` (default row height) to `20` and so I still have one line in the cells.

I called this method after the line

```
        jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));            
        updateRowHeights();
```

I will really appreciate any help that will put my feet on the right track to make this work for me..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

Default renderer/editor doesn't support multiple lines. You can try to use custom `TableCellEditor`/`TableCellRenderer`. Examine next example with `JTextArea` in table cell:

```
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    public TestFrame() {
        init();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        JTable t = new JTable(new Object[][]{{"a\n\rb","1"},{"a\n\rb","2"}},new Object[]{1,2});

        add(new JScrollPane(t));
        t.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new JTextAreaColumn());
        t.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new JTextAreaColumn());
        t.setRowHeight(50);
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new TestFrame();
    }


    private class JTextAreaColumn extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellRenderer,TableCellEditor {

        private JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
        private JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(area);

        @Override
        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return area.getText();
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table,
                Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
            area.setText(value == null ? "" : value.toString());        
            return pane;
        }

        private void setColor(boolean isSelected, JTable table) {
            area.setBackground(isSelected ? table.getSelectionBackground() : table.getBackground());
            area.setForeground(isSelected ? table.getSelectionForeground() : table.getForeground());
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
                int column) {
            area.setText(value == null ? "" : value.toString());
            setColor(isSelected,table);
            return pane;
        }

    }

}
```

[image]

Read more in [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)

EDIT:

Try next, seems it what you want;

```
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    private JTable t;


    public TestFrame() {
        init();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        t = new JTable(new Object[][]{{"a\n\rb","1"},{"a\n\rb\n\rb\n\rb\n\rb","2"}},new Object[]{1,2});

        add(new JScrollPane(t));
        t.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new JTextAreaColumn());
        JTextAreaColumn editor = new JTextAreaColumn();
        editor.addCellEditorListener(getEditorListener());
        t.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(editor);
        updateRowHeights(t);
    }

    private CellEditorListener getEditorListener() {
        return new CellEditorListener() {

            @Override
            public void editingStopped(ChangeEvent e) {
                updateRowHeights(t);
            }

            @Override
            public void editingCanceled(ChangeEvent e) {
                updateRowHeights(t);
            }
        };
    }

    private void updateRowHeights(JTable table) {
        try {
            for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
                int rowHeight = table.getRowHeight();

                for (int column = 0; column < table.getColumnCount(); column++) {
                    Component comp = table.prepareRenderer(
                            table.getCellRenderer(row, column), row, column);
                    rowHeight = Math.max(rowHeight,
                            comp.getPreferredSize().height);
                }

                table.setRowHeight(row, rowHeight);
            }
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new TestFrame();
    }


    private class JTextAreaColumn extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellRenderer,TableCellEditor {

        private JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
        private JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(area);

        @Override
        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return area.getText();
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table,
                Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
            area.setText(value == null ? "" : value.toString());        
            return pane;
        }

        private void setColor(boolean isSelected, JTable table) {
            area.setBackground(isSelected ? table.getSelectionBackground() : table.getBackground());
            area.setForeground(isSelected ? table.getSelectionForeground() : table.getForeground());
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
                int column) {
            area.setText(value == null ? "" : value.toString());
            setColor(isSelected,table);
            return area;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks alex2410 but the code that I need should provide the height of the row automatically. The row height will depend on the length of the string. some will have tow lines some will have 3 or more and some will have 1 (single) line only. I am still trying to figure it out and will appreciate if someone could show a way to do it :)

Comment: You can do that, just return `area` in `getTableCellEditorComponent`/`getTableCellRendererComponent` , but you need to use `JScrollPane` with `JTeatArea`.