# JTable not honoring cell renderer's necessary height

Tags: java, swing, tablecellrenderer

This should be simple, but I can't figure out what is going wrong.  I need my table to display with a fairly large font size but the table painter is not honoring the height of the cell renderer.

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783607/auto-adjust-the-height-of-rows-in-a-jtable) and it's working brilliantly for when my preferences window has been given a changed font size.  But although the renderer knows what font size to use, the table *on initial display* is using the standard row height (16). Surely the table painter should automatically take into account the preferred height of the renderer?  Or do I actually have to manually tell it what height to use?

I've tried a call to `doLayout()` as shown below, but it doesn't make any difference.

Here's an SSCCE to demonstrate the problem:

```
public class IncorrectRowHeight extends JPanel
{
    private class MyCellRenderer extends JTextField implements TableCellRenderer
    {
        private MyCellRenderer()
        {
            setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 30));
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                                                       int row, int column)
        {
            setText(value.toString());
            return this;
        }
    }

    public IncorrectRowHeight()
    {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        add(new JTextField(25), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        String[][] data = {
                {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"},
                {"f", "g", "h", "i", "j"},
                {"k", "l", "m", "n", "o"},
                {"p", "q", "r", "s", "t"}
        };
        String[] cols = {"h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5"};
        JTable t = new JTable(data, cols);
        t.setGridColor(Color.GRAY);
        t.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(300, 65));
        TableColumnModel model = t.getColumnModel();
        for (int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++)
        {
            TableColumn column = model.getColumn(i);
            column.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
        }
        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(t);
        add(scroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //t.doLayout();  // doesn't help matters
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("IncorrectRowHeight");
        JComponent newContentPane = new IncorrectRowHeight();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It produces the following:

[image]

This ain't rocket science!  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `JTable` uses the `rowHeight` property to determine the height of the rows. You might consider using it to try and estimate the best height for the rows

Comment: So, in other words I need to tell JTable what height to use, there's no way it's going to be intelligent enough to figure it out from the cell renderers???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use table.setRowHeight(table.getFontMetrics(font).getHeight());

```
package com.logicbig.example;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;
import java.awt.*;

public class IncorrectRowHeight extends JPanel {
private static final Font font = new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 30);
private class MyCellRenderer extends JTextField implements TableCellRenderer {
    private MyCellRenderer() {
        setFont(font);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                                                   int row, int column) {
        setText(value.toString());
        return this;
    }
}

public IncorrectRowHeight() {
    super(new BorderLayout());

    add(new JTextField(25), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    String[][] data = {
            {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"},
            {"f", "g", "h", "i", "j"},
            {"k", "l", "m", "n", "o"},
            {"p", "q", "r", "s", "t"}
    };
    String[] cols = {"h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5"};
    JTable t = new JTable(data, cols);
    t.setRowHeight(t.getFontMetrics(font).getHeight());
    t.setGridColor(Color.GRAY);
    t.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(300, 65));
    TableColumnModel model = t.getColumnModel();
    for (int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        TableColumn column = model.getColumn(i);
        column.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
    }
    JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(t);
    add(scroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //t.doLayout();  // doesn't help matters
}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("IncorrectRowHeight");
    JComponent newContentPane = new IncorrectRowHeight();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
  }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: I really like the use of getFontMetrics(), thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 2):

Probably this method help you

```
public static void updateRowHeight(JTable table, int margin) {
    final int rowCount = table.getRowCount();
    final int colCount = table.getColumnCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        int maxHeight = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++) {
            final TableCellRenderer renderer = table.getCellRenderer(i, j);
            maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, table.prepareRenderer(renderer, i, j).getPreferredSize().height);
        }
        table.setRowHeight(i, maxHeight + margin);
    }
}
```

Use this method after the table is populated with the data. `margin` parameter is used for additional increment of row height. If not required - use 0.

Here is your example with the correct cell height.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

/**
 * <code>IncorrectRowHeight</code>.
 */
public class IncorrectRowHeight extends JPanel {
    private class MyCellRenderer extends JTextField implements TableCellRenderer {
        private MyCellRenderer() {
            setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 30));
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
                int column) {
            setText(value.toString());
            return this;
        }
    }

    public IncorrectRowHeight() {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        add(new JTextField(25), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        String[][] data = {{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}, {"f", "g", "h", "i", "j"}, {"k", "l", "m", "n", "o"}, {"p", "q", "r", "s", "t"}};
        String[] cols = {"h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5"};
        JTable t = new JTable(data, cols);
        t.setGridColor(Color.GRAY);
        t.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(300, 65));
        TableColumnModel model = t.getColumnModel();
        for (int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            TableColumn column = model.getColumn(i);
            column.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
        }
        updateRowHeight(t, 0);
        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(t);
        add(scroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void updateRowHeight(JTable table, int margin) {
        final int rowCount = table.getRowCount();
        final int colCount = table.getColumnCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            int maxHeight = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++) {
                final TableCellRenderer renderer = table.getCellRenderer(i, j);
                maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, table.prepareRenderer(renderer, i, j).getPreferredSize().height);
            }
            table.setRowHeight(i, maxHeight + margin);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("IncorrectRowHeight");
        JComponent newContentPane = new IncorrectRowHeight();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this would be good for the case where different rows need to be of different heights.  In my case that's not necessary.